# Perform a search based on cascading dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am building an app that allows users to select the car of their choice based on a set of criteria.

Those criteria are:

**Condition** of the car (New, Used, Sold)

**Year** of car (from 1900 to 2013 and we would include 2014 when they role into the market)

**Price** of car($0 - $10,000, all the way to over $20,000)

**Type** of car (convertibles, sports utititilies, sedans,etc)

**Make** of car (Acura, Lexus, Toyota, Mazda, etc)

**Model** of car (Legend, Camry, Corolla, etc)

All of the above criteria are dropdownlist controls populated from the database.

So far, I am able to create cascading dropdownlist controls for Year, Make, and Model.

User selects Year of car, say 1987 from the **ddlYear** dropdownlist and all Makes built for the year 1987 are automatically populated into the **ddlMake** dropdownlist.

Then when user selects Make, the model for that make and for that year are automatically populated into the **ddlModel** dropdownlist control.

This part works fine.

What I really need your help on is how to construct the code that allows a user to select Condition from **ddlCondition** dropdownlist, Year from **ddlYear** dropdownlist, Price range from the **ddlPrice** dropdownlist, Car type from the **ddlType** dropdownlist, Make of the car from the **ddlMake** dropdownlist and finally, the model from the **ddlModel** dropdownlist and then click the Search button to display results.

```
' SQL Query (base)
Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM YourVehiclesTable WHERE "

'Begin checking our values and appending to our clauses

'If  Condition has a value 
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlCondition.SelectedValue) Then
    'Append to query
    sql += String.Format(" Condition = '{0}' AND", ddlCondition.SelectedValue)
End If

'Check Year
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlYear.SelectedValue) Then
    'Append to query
    sql += String.Format(" Year = '{0}' AND", ddlYear.SelectedValue)
End If

'Check Price
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlPrice.SelectedValue) Then
    'Append to query
    sql += String.Format(" Price <= '{0}' AND", ddlPrice.SelectedValue)
End If

'continue with rest

'When we are finished make sure to strip off any remaining "AND" and "WHERE"s that may be present at the end
sql = sql.TrimEnd(" WHERE ").TrimEnd("AND")
```

I am not quite sure how to put it all together in such that a user selects Condition, Year, Price, Vehicle Type, Make, Model and click the Search button to display results.

Is there a better approach than the approach I am using with shown code?

Thank you in advance for your great assistance.

Please see screenshot.

[image]

Comment: The query seems to be rightly formed and thus the only remaining bit is communicating it to the DB and dealing with the returned information. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: @varocarbas, thanks for your response.

I have a cascading dropdownlist, where user selects year from ddlyear and then makes of certains cars for that year get populated into ddlMake dropdownlist. Then when user selects his/her preferred car make, say Lexus from the dllMake dropdownlist,the ddlModel dropdownlist is enabled and populated with models for selected make. I did not post that code. How do I integrate with code I posted above?

Comment: I do understand what you are doing and I guess that the comboboxes are being populated rightly on account of the selections. What the code you posted does is building up a query to the database on account of the given selections on these comboboxes and it seems (cannot be sure without seeing your DB) to be right. The only thing you need to do now is communication with the DB with this query and deal with the returned information. Is this what you are asking for? Don't you know how to send this query to the DB and deal with the returned values?

Comment: Are you looking for help with the [tag:sql] query or the [tag:vb.net] code?

Answer (score 3):

Is there a better approach? Yes, I think there is.

Where I do this sort of searching using multiple parameters where there's no guarantee of which parameters are entered or not, I use a stored procedure; trying to dynamically write a SQL query like you've shown in your question is, to me, too error-prone (plus you run the risk of SQL injection).

The stored procedure definition has a parameter for each criterion you want to use, and defaults each parameter to `NULL`, then in the body of the query we can easily exclude any parameter that is still `NULL` e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE VehicleSearch 
(
    @Condition NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Year NVARCHAR(4) = NULL,
    @Make NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Model NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
)
AS

SELECT
    *
FROM
    YourVehiclesTable v
WHERE
    (@Condition IS NULL OR v.Condition = @Condition)
AND
    (@Year IS NULL = OR v.Year = @Year)
AND
    (@Make IS NULL OR v.Make = @Make)
AND
    (@Model IS NULL or v.Model = @Model)
```

When your Search button is clicked, you call the stored procedure, passing only the parameters that the user selected; the other parameters will default to NULL and be excluded from the query.

Comment: and varocarbas, thank you both.

I guess where I am still confused is this, the dropdownlist is cascading. In other words, before you can select Make, you must select Year first and before you can select Model, you must select Make first.

In your example, it appears though as Year, Make and Model are separate.

Maybe, you guys are right and I am not understanding the logic you guys are referencing. 

Either that or I am not explaining it well.

I was under the impression that because these 3 dropdowns cascade, you can only search by last selected, in the case, the model

Comment: I would be very careful with this approach, although it may be neater code wise it often results in a index or table scan rather than a seek which if there are a lot of options can severely hit performance.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use a level parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchIt
(
    @Condition VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Year VARCHAR(4) = NULL,
    @Make VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Model VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Level INT
)
AS


IF (@Level = 1)
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE VehCondition = @Condition

END

ELSE IF (@Level = 2)
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE VehCondition = @Condition
    AND VehYear = @Year

END

ELSE IF (@Level = 3)
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE VehCondition = @Condition
    AND VehYear = @Year
    AND VehPrice = @Price

END

ELSE IF (@Level = 4)
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE VehCondition = @Condition
    AND VehYear = @Year
    AND VehPrice = @Price
    AND VehType = @Type

END
```

Comment: thank you too. Are you suggesting that I shouldn't use dependent approach? In other words, just load year, load make, load model and then use the code? My issue with that is to consider that each year, there are several makes and models of vehicles. So, filtering with Year, selecting Make based on what year is selected, and selecting model based on what make helps users to NOT scroll through lots of records before finding what they are looking for.

By the way, what are those levels for?

Comment: The level defines which element(s) to search for, eg Level 1 is first and filters only by condition, level 2 is used when the user selects the year and filters by year AND condition. Using the approach suggested by Phil will work but may be slower the more rows you are filtering, if it is less than 10,000 rows then either will be fine probably.

Comment: I understand now.

However, isn't there anyway to handle cascading (dependent fields)?

As stated, the value for model is dependent on what value is selected for Make and the value for Make is dependent on the value for Year.

I don't mind re-arranging the dropdown to start with Condition, Price, Type, Year, Make, Model if this helps.

Comment: This only works if you have a strict order you want to run through the fields, what I'd do is use this to return a result set then from that extract a distinct list of the next type to fill the next drop down (while also optionally displaying the results).